# Two equivalent statements about $R$-modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a ring with $1$.
All $R$-modules below are left $R$-modules.

Let $F$ be an $R$-module. Then we have two equivalent statements on $F$.

*Statement 1*: $F = \bigoplus_{i \in I} Rv_i$ is a direct sum of a family $\{ R v_i \mid i \in I \}$ of cyclic submodules with $Rv_i \cong R$ for all $i$.

*Statement 2*: $F$ is an $R$-module isomorphic to a direct sum of copies of the same $R$-module $R$.

From statement (1) to statement (2) it is trivial, but I cannot work out the converse direction. The book I am reading says this direction is also trivial … and there is no proof of “(2) $\implies$ (1)”.

My question is how can we prove “(2) $\implies$ (1)”. Thanks for help.

---

Some more background: These two statements come from a preliminary part before the introduction of free modules. I just know some basic properties of $R$ modules up to now.

Comment: Try the simplest case when $|I| = 2$, i.e. $F \cong R \oplus R$. What do you think $v_{1}$ and $v_{2}$ should be?

Comment: Note that the direct sum $R^{(I)}$ of $|I|$ copies of $R$ is the (internal) direct sum $\bigoplus_{i \in I} Re_i$, where $e_i \in R^{(I)}$ has a $1$ in the $i$-th coordinate and $0$ everywhere else.

Comment: @azif00 Thanks for the comment. I was confused because the book didn't say which space $v_i$ should be in. With your comment, we have $F\cong \oplus_{i\in I} Re_i$. We can not have a strict equal sign as in the statement, i.e. $F=\oplus_{i\in I} Re_i$, right?

Comment: @SamWong Use an isomorphism $R^{(I)} \to F$ to take the equality $R^{(I)} = \bigoplus_{i \in I} Re_i$ to an equality of the form $F = \bigoplus_{i \in I} Rv_i$.